# Update ng-class on HTML tag when routing

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-extension, angular-routing, ng-class

I'm writing a Chrome extension using AngularJS. The UI is served via a browser action popup and as the content changes I sometimes need to change the size of the popup. The only way I've been able to do this is to change the CSS sizing attributes on the HTML and BODY tags via conditional updates of the class, i.e.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="oApp" ng-controller="QuestionsCtrl" ng-class="{true:'expand'}[doExpand]">
<head>
...
</head>
<body ng-class="{true:'expand'}[doExpand]">
...
```

I have an ng-click on a control that sets 'doExpand' and this works nicely. However, I'm updating the app now to use routing to display multiple views. In doing that I'm removing the inline controller declaration...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="oApp" ng-class="{true:'expand'}[doExpand]">
...
```

... and defining it in the routing config:

```
var oApp = angular.module('oApp', ['ngRoute', 'oControllers']);
oApp.config(['$routeProvider',
function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/login', {
        templateUrl: '/partials/login.html',
        controller: 'LoginCtrl'
    }).
    when('/board', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/board.html',
        controller: 'QuestionsCtrl'
    }).
    when('/board/:questionId', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/question-detail.html',
        controller: 'QuestionDetailCtrl'
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/login'
    });
}
]);
```

The routing is working but the problem is that the HTML tag is now outside the scope of the controller since that's now on the views themselves. I can stick the BODY tag in the views I suppose, but can't do the same for the HTML tag since the JS includes need to be in the head, etc. (and other reasons)

Can someone offer me advice on how to handle this scenario? Thank you!

Comment: One option would be to make a new controller that is responsible for expanding and place it in the same place that `QuestionsCtrl` used to be.

Comment: +1 The problem with that is I have a lot more functionality for the view that triggers the update, but your comment did lead me to a possible solution - remove the controller definition in the routing config for that view only and instead put it where it used to go inline. This is not really scalable but may work for now. If there's a cleaner way to do it I'm all ears.  :)  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: can add parameters to each route config if that helps( or just the ones that need `doDexpand`. Then add simple directive to listen to routeChange events and set `scope.doExpand` in directive

Comment: Thanks @charliefl! That may work, but I just got a version going by taking Davin's advise with a new controller on the HTML tag and using $emit and $on to communicate from the trigger control.